# JMeter Selenium plugin Kernel32 exception

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

i have been trying to setup Selenium plugins for JMeter for a day already and i can't figure out how to solve this exception. I have tried replacing selenium jar's, switching versions and still i get this one.

JMeter version: 2.13
Selenium libs: 2.46.0

```
Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:248)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.quit(FirefoxBinary.java:259)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.quit(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:376)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.stopClient(FirefoxDriver.java:322)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:477)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.quitBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:269)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadFinished(WebDriverConfig.java:244)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:612)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:584)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you please post the code where you initialize your driver/selenium (firefox webdriver etc)?

Comment: There is no code apart from the default inits that come with the Webdriver sample, they are:                           WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like plugin packaging issue and presumably caused by libraries clash between the ones, shipped with JMeter and the ones, which come with the WebDriver plugin.

Inspect /lib folder of your JMeter installation, detect libraries with same names but different versions and remove duplicates.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver sampler tips and tricks.

Comment: yea removing old versions of duplicates made it start chromedriver and it worked. But from jmeter console It still throws Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32. See log file for details.

Answer (score 0):

The Error comes when the following issues are met:

1. In the Lib folder, multiple jars with different versions are present.
2. platform.jar is not present in lib folder
3. jna.jar are not present is not present in lib folder.

To solve the issue:
1. Install platform.jar and jna.jar in the lib folder and delete all the jar files with the same name.